# Difference between "extending Application" and sharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am looking to store simple variables so that if the app process is stopped the data will still be available when it relaunches.  I looked into extending the Application class and sharedPreferences.  To me, it seems that extending Application is good for temporary global variables that are deleted when the app process is stopped.  sharedPreferences however saves the variable onto a file so that is is always available.  What are the differences between the two, and what are their optimal uses?  Also, what is the best for storing variables that you want to keep even if the app is stopped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your app's process is killed, any data stored in the Application class will be lost. You should only use that for storing data that is not needed across multiple launches and uses of your app.

For storing simple data like highscores, sound preference, showing a dialog at startup preference, your best bet would be SharedPreferences. For more comprehensive data, like a list of purchases made by an user in your app, or notes in a todo list app, you should use an SQLite Database.

Beyond that, if you want to store files like PDFs etc. or images (images can also be saved into a database), you can use the internal storage or the external storage (may be an SD Card, or a partition on the internal storage). Please keep in mind that on most devices, internal storage is very limited and you shouldn't save excessively large file there.

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) part of the documentation should help you with storage options.